# Neo4J Subgraph Labelling and accessing it back

Tags: neo4j, pattern-matching, graph-databases

I am considering a pattern matching activity using Neo4J Graph DB. There are n number of patterns I want to match in a database, but each node will be matched only to one pattern. The nodes that are returned by the cypher match query will be assigned `patternName` property. But to avoid duplication of patternName property for each node in a subgraph (pattern), I am exploring options to group that subgraph and label it as a whole, such that using that label I would be able to access that whole pattern again.

Tried

1. `Vnodes by APOC`- But these don't persists, hence I won't be able to get the for a particular patternName using virtual Nodes
2. `Grouping by APOC`- but this grouping is based on a particular property, I want to add a new property for a whole group.

What are the options I can go with? Is this possible.

I am avoiding to create a new node for every pattern, also not trying to duplicate the properties for all the nodes in one pattern.

Comment: What is the nature of the pattern? Numbers, letters, words, ???

Answer (score 0):

Since a node can have any number of [labels](https://neo4j.com/docs/getting-started/appendix/graphdb-concepts/#graphdb-labels), you can add an appropriate pattern label to each node. Such labels persist in the DB and do not require new nodes, relationships, or properties.

Comment: If the intent is to query and set up relationships of the pattern node with other nodes, then a property would be the best solution and not a label. The question is ambiguous on this and also on the nature of the pattern.

Comment: @DavidAStumpf: I don't follow. Please explain.

Comment: I have patterns of shared DNA segment that create clusters of different groups who share the pattern. The individual patterns are represented as relationships between people and segments. The agglomerative communities have the same shared segments and the community id representing the community becomes a property of the individuals. Since there are multiple communities with different individuals, having the community id in a person node makes for an efficient query rather than having different node labels.

Comment: What I am describing is best called a hierarchical graph rather than a subgrqaph.  THe most robust way to manage the hierarchy is with ORDPATH.

Comment: I don't think having a community ID in every Person node is more efficient, and can easily be less so. It all depends on your exact queries.